# PHP copy a field of Object Array to a simple Array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, bash

I have a `PHP` `Object Array` with several fields and I need to extract all the equal fields and store them into `individual arrays`, because I need to pass them to a `bash script`, and I prefer to have separate arrays, because `bash` is no object oriented right?

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php 
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

$text_array = "'" . implode ("\n", $data->text) . "'";
$time_text = "'" . implode ("\n", $data->time_text) . "'";
$gender = "'" . implode ("\n", $data->gender) . "'";
$pitch = "'" . implode ("\n", $data->pitch) . "'";

$response = shell_exec("./test_bash.sh $pitch $gender $timetext $text_array 2>&1");

echo "$response";

?>
```

The data is passed from `javascript` to `PHP` through `ajax`. The original `Object Array` has this structure:

```
text
time_text
gender
pitch
```

and I create the `Object Array` in `Javascript` like:

```
function dataClass(text, time_txt, gender, pitch, mood) {
        this.text = text;
        this.time_text = time_txt;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.pitch = pitch;
        this.mood = mood;
}
for(var i = 0; i < length - 1; i++){
    data.push(new dataToSynth(subtitles_trans[i].text, subtitles_trans[i].end - subtitles_trans[i].start, genere, pitch));
}
```

How can I copy the object array fields to a individual arrays, in PHP?

Comment: no need to use json_decode. its passed as normal array. Try $data = $_POST['data']; echo $data['text'];

Comment: How can I copy the object array fields to a individual arrays, in PHP, because is not working :S

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use json_decode. In your case "$_POST['data']" is an array, not an object. Try this code:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];

$text_array = "'" . implode ("\n", $data['text']) . "'";
$time_text = "'" . implode ("\n", $data['time_text']) . "'";
$gender = "'" . implode ("\n", $data['gender']) . "'";
$pitch = "'" . implode ("\n", $data['pitch']) . "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast object values into array just you cast an string to int.

```
<?php
class a{
    public $a="a";
    public $b="b";
    public $c="c";
}

$a= new a();

$b= (array)$a;

var_dump($a);
/*object(a)#1 (3) {
    ["a"]=>
       string(1) "a"
    ["b"]=>
       string(1) "b"
    ["c"]=>
       string(1) "c"
}*/
var_dump($b);
/*array(3) {
    ["a"]=>
       string(1) "a"
    ["b"]=>
       string(1) "b"
    ["c"]=>
       string(1) "c"
}*/
```

So it should be like this:

```
<?php 
$data =(array) json_decode($_POST['data']);

$text_array = "'" . implode ("\n", $data['text']) . "'";
$time_text = "'" . implode ("\n", $data['time_text']) . "'";
$gender = "'" . implode ("\n", $data['gender']) . "'";
$pitch = "'" . implode ("\n", $data['pitch']) . "'";

$response = shell_exec("./test_bash.sh $pitch $gender $timetext $text_array 2>&1");

echo "$response";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm trying this, but I can't echo the individual arrays because nothing is showed... But the array is OK before to be send through ajax... I'm doing this in PHP: 
foreach ($text_array as $key => $value) {
   echo $value;
}